# How to refer sibling elements in json?

Tags: json

I'm new to java script, i want to do the following but getting error ,
here , variable pug, sass etc refers to  root (variable r). How can i achieve it ?

in short i want to refer sibling elements in  Json?

Json code that i tried,

```
var devpath = {
          r : 'src',
           pug : r + "/pug", 
          sass : r + "/sass",
           css : r + "/css",
            js : r + "/js",
        images : r + "/images",
        vendor : r + "/vendor"

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are expecting:

```
var r = 'src';

var devpath = {
          'r' : r,
           'pug' : r + "/pug", 
          'sass' : r + "/sass",
           'css' : r + "/css",
            'js' : r + "/js",
        'images' : r + "/images",
        'vendor' : r + "/vendor"
}
```

Comment: is there any other way so that i dont have to write 1st line?

Comment: No, because it evaluates the structure as a unit, and `devpath.r` doesn't exist yet when evaluating the structure